# Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup subclass - 'visible' v 'is_visible'

Tags: setup-script

I'm looking at a setup/install script which extends from **Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup** and noticed that some of the attributes in the return array of the getDefaultEntities method have a **'visible' key** (e.g. 'visible' => true) while others have an **'is_visible' key**.

Is there a difference between the two? Is one just an unsupported typo that didn't get noticed and got copied and pasted too much?

None of the other Setup.php files in app/code/community or app/code/local use 'is_visible'.

I'm loath to change anything, but I'd like to understand what the differences might be.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is the following:

When using `->addAttribute()` the thing is called "visible", but when using `updateAttribute()`, it is "is_visible"

Update: They refer to the same thing, but the addAttribute() method (I think) defines a mapping, so the shorter version is used.

Comment: only when the setup resource is of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`. The mapping is defined there in the method `_prepareValues`.

Comment: @Thorsten Thanks for naming the method, that is the one I meant. :)

Comment: You are right. The `addAttribute` in the both `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` transform `visible` to `is_visible`. Anyway, the base class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` should not be used. Only one of the 2 mentioned above because you can add attributes either to a catalog entity (category, product) or a customer entity (customer, address). If it's a custom entity it should have it's own setup model.